# rand() is not returning random values

Tags: c, linux, gcc, matrix, libc

Its a small code to generate a random hermitian matrix [hermitian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).

I have called srand() before every call to rand(). but still no randomness in the output.

I have used c99's complex datatype feature to create a hermitian matrix. I'm not sure where i'm wrong :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MATSIZE 5
#define RAND_RANGE 100

double complex mat[MATSIZE][MATSIZE];

void gen_mat()
{
  int i =0,j;
  int real;
  int img;
  for( ;i < MATSIZE; i++)
  {
    srand(time(NULL));
    real = rand()%RAND_RANGE + 1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    img = rand()%RAND_RANGE + 1;
    for(j = MATSIZE; j != i ; j--) 
    { 
       mat[i][j] = real + img * I;
       mat[j][i] = conj(mat[i][j]);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    if(i == j)
      mat[i][i] = rand()%RAND_RANGE + 0*I;
  }
}

void print_mat()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < MATSIZE; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < MATSIZE; j++)
    {
      printf("%f + %f *i", creal(mat[i][j]), cimag(mat[i][j]));
      printf("    ");
    }
    puts("\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
  gen_mat();
  print_mat();
  return 0;
}
```

sample output

```
[aft@centos-c physics-numaric]$ ./a.out 
66.000000 + 0.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i             67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    

67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    66.000000 + 0.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i      67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    

67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    66.000000 + 0.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    

67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    66.000000 + 0.000000 *i    67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    

67.000000 + 67.000000 *i    67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    67.000000 + -67.000000 *i      67.000000 + -67.000000 *i    66.000000 + 0.000000 *i
```

EDIT calling srand in main() actually solved the problem. Thank you guys.

```
[aft@centos-c physics-numaric]$ ./a.out 
31.000000 + 0.000000 *i    81.000000 + 75.000000 *i    81.000000 + 75.000000 *i     81.000000 + 75.000000 *i    81.000000 + 75.000000 *i    

81.000000 + -75.000000 *i    53.000000 + 0.000000 *i    69.000000 + 57.000000 *i    69.000000 + 57.000000 *i    69.000000 + 57.000000 *i    

69.000000 + 57.000000 *i    69.000000 + -57.000000 *i    27.000000 + 0.000000 *i    93.000000 + 11.000000 *i    93.000000 + 11.000000 *i    

93.000000 + 11.000000 *i    69.000000 + -57.000000 *i    93.000000 + -11.000000 *i    58.000000 + 0.000000 *i    76.000000 + 78.000000 *i    

76.000000 + 78.000000 *i    69.000000 + -57.000000 *i    93.000000 + -11.000000 *i    76.000000 + -78.000000 *i    67.000000 + 0.000000 *i
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't call `srand` before every call to `rand`.  Call it once when your program starts.

Comment: @aftnix: I think there's a timer, so you can only accept an answer 10 minutes after you asked the question.

Comment: Charlseworth people really gave a lot of thought behind these stack exchange app design. cool dynamics :)

Comment: i clicked on the "flag" of this answer by accident. how to undo it?

Answer (score 6):

Don't call `srand` inside if the loop. Call it only once.

```
srand(time(NULL));
for( ;i < MATSIZE; i++)
{
    // ... calls to rand()   
}
```

Otherwise you seed the random generator with the same seed (as it is fast enough to get the same time)

BTW, many times I find it very conventional to create an init function for the program / sequence where I initialize many things, including the random generation (e.g. call `srand()`)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to seed the random number generator with `srand()` every time! Just call it once at the beginning of your program. Then call `rand()` to get the next random number.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
rand()%RAND_RANGE + 0*I;
```

, since it will cause the lower values to be oversampled if RAND_RANGE and RAND_MAX+1 don't divide. (which "almost always" is the case)

Also: restarting the generator based on time(NULL) will in most cases restart with exactly the same value, since the granularity of time_t is one second.

Final: rand_max will have *at least* 15 bits (32K) worth of random. Older systems might actually deliver only 15 bits, with a cycle of 32 K.

UPDATE: this is a snippet from [wakkerbot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/files/). The urnd() function attempts to return an unbiased value between 0 and range. The test can probably be performed more elegantly.

```
typedef unsigned long long BigThing;

unsigned int urnd(unsigned int range)
{
    static bool flag = FALSE;

    if (flag == FALSE) {
#if defined(__mac_os) || defined(DOS)
        srand(time(NULL));
#else
        srand48(time(NULL));
#endif
    }
    flag = TRUE;
#if defined(__mac_os) || defined(DOS)
    return rand()%range;
#else

if (range <= 1) return 0;

while(1)        {
    BigThing val, box;
#if WANT_RDTSC_RANDOM
    val = rdtsc_rand();
#else
    val =  lrand48();
#endif
/* we need this to avoid oversampling of the lower values.
 * Oversampling the lower values becomes more of a problem if (UNSIGNED_MAX/range) gets smaller
 */
    box = val / range;
    if ((1+box) *range < range) continue;
    return val % range;
        }
#endif
}
```

Comment: So what's your suggestion ? how should i take a random value and also maintain a range properly?

Comment: The idea is: if you get a sample from the top of the range, just before wrap-around happens: reject it and redraw. For example, if RAND_MAX is 10, and your RAND_RANGE is 4: reject values >=8, otherwise return value%RAND_RANGE. (otherwise the values {0,1} would have larger chance of uccuring in the output than {2,3}) I'll add a snippet to my reply.