# Program doesn't work when rrun normally, but with debug step by step the result is right

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

In the code below, which I wrote on visual studio 2013, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> but don't print the right result, I debug it step by step the results is right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int randfoo(void)
{
time_t ts;
int a[10];
unsigned int randdata = time(&ts);
srand(randdata);
return (rand() % 100);

}

int randNumber(int  firstNum, int  lastNumber, int result[][6])
{
int ret_val = -1;
int value1;

if ((firstNum > 0) && (firstNum < 5))
{
    if ((lastNumber>0) && (lastNumber < 7))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstNum; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < lastNumber; j++)
            {
                value1 = randfoo();
                result[i][j] = value1;
                printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n", i, j, result[i][j]);

            }
        }
        ret_val = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ret_val = -1;
    }
}
else
{
    ret_val = -1;
}
return ret_val;
 }

void main()
{
int buff[4][6];
randNumber(4, 6, buff);

system("pause");
}
```

the first function randfoo just  to generate a rand number.
the second function  randNumber in order to put the rand number into the result[4][6],and print the results.

Comment: Are you saying when you run the program, it doesnt work properly as in it crashes in some way? Or does it not output the correct info?

Comment: Suggestion: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 1):

You used `srand(randdata);` on each call to `randfoo()`. `srand()` is used to *seed* the PRNG for `rand()`. You don't seed it every time.

Just use `srand(randdata)` once in `main()` and `rand() % 100` directly in all the assignments.

You can get rid of the whole `randfoo()` function, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but I changed my codes as your direction,it still can not work.

Comment: sorry for my last commit .Follow your advice ,it really works.after i have checked my code carefully ,i found i forget a "()"to use function "randfoo()".Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Random wont be random enough if you access it again and again repeatedly in the time of CPU cycles. To read more about rand please read [this](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) page.

> The **period** of rand is implementation defined, but typically falls
>   around 2^32-1. Compare this with the Mersenne Twister algorithm, which
>   is 2^19937-1. You typically want the period of a random number
>   generator to exceed the amount of numbers expected to be generated,
>   because that's the point where the sequence repeats.

From another answer in SO ([source link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259041/1155650)):

> Don't call srand before every call to rand. Call it once when your
>   program starts.

You may want to look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259028/rand-is-not-returning-random-values).

Comment: It is very kind of you! That ,the information you offered, is  really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to explain the reason it "works" when you debug it and "doesn't work" when you run it.

When you run it normally it executes in much less time than 1 second. Thus, the `time()` function always returns the same time (unless you get very lucky and run it exactly on a second boundary) and thus you call `srand()` with the same value and so `rand()` returns the same value for each call to `randfoo()`.

When you debug it, however, it probably takes a few seconds between calls to `randfoo()` thus you get different `time()` values, which seeds the pseudo-random generator with different values, and thus different `rand()` values.

A great example of a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), a bug that disappears when you try to find it. The solution, as the other answers say, is to simply call `srand()` once at the program start.